# SASS: MIXIN for set heights

Tags: css, sass

First time asking here.

I'm trying to make somekind of MIXIN in order to set heights for an element.

For example `< span class="space h5" >< /span >` in CSS this would be:

```
$size: 1px;

.space {

display: block;

}

.space.x5 {

height: $size * 5;

}
```

So my question, is it possible to create a mixin to multiply, add up or subtract amounts with classes?

For example

```
< span class=" space h5 x2 add4 ">< /span > ====> height: 14px
```

or:

```
< span class=" space h5 x4 subtract2 ">< /span > ====> height: 18px
```

Thanks a lot!

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@mixin height-special($default,$multiplier: 1,$extra: 0) {
  height: ($default*$multiplier+$extra) + px;
}
```

So, height-special(5,2,4) will return 14
you can leave out the last 2 which will return the default value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice solution but I was looking for something more like a loop:

```
.space {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

$space-base: 5px;

/*multipliers*/
@for $space-base from 1 through 100 {
  .h5x#{$space-base} {
    height:  $space-base * 5px;
  }
}

/*add*/
.h5x2.add-1 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 1);
}
.h5x2.add-2 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 2);
}
.h5x2.add-3 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 3);
}
.h5x2.add-4 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 4);
}
.h5x2.add-5 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 5);
}
.h5x2.add-6 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 6);
}
.h5x2.add-7 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 7);
}
.h5x2.add-8 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 8);
}
.h5x2.add-9 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  + 9);
}
/*subtract*/
.h5x2.sub-1 {
  height: ($space-base * 2  - 1);
}
```

I was trying to avoid all the combination by hand and do it with SASS.